# Could not find table of contents resource. in android while reading epub content

Tags: android, epub

I am trying to read and display the content of epub in android using

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView webview;
String line, line1 = "", finalstr = "";
int i = 0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream epubInputStream = assetManager
                .open("life.epub");
        Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);

        // Log the book's authors
        Log.i("author", " : " + book.getMetadata().getAuthors());

        // Log the book's title
        Log.i("title", " : " + book.getTitle());
        // Log the tale of contents
        logTableOfContents(book.getTableOfContents().getTocReferences(), 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("epublib exception", e.getMessage());
    }

    String javascrips = "";
    try {
        // InputStream input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lights);
        InputStream input = this.getAssets().open(
                "life.epub");
        int size;
        size = input.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        input.read(buffer);
        input.close();
        // byte buffer into a string
        javascrips = new String(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // String html = readFile(is);

    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", javascrips,
            "application/epub+zip", "UTF-8", null);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void logTableOfContents(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth) {
    if (tocReferences == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (TOCReference tocReference : tocReferences) {
        StringBuilder tocString = new StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
         tocString.append("\t");
         }
         tocString.append(tocReference.getTitle());
         Log.i("TOC", tocString.toString());

        try {
            InputStream is = tocReference.getResource().getInputStream();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                // line1 = Html.fromHtml(line).toString();
                Log.v("line" + i, Html.fromHtml(line).toString());
                // line1 = (tocString.append(Html.fromHtml(line).toString()+
                // "\n")).toString();
                line1 = line1.concat(Html.fromHtml(line).toString());
            }
            finalstr = finalstr.concat("\n").concat(line1);
            // Log.v("Content " + i, finalstr);
            i++;
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        logTableOfContents(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1);
    }
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", finalstr, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
}
}
```

my logcat is showing  one warning and displaying in logacat as

```
 02-04 16:33:54.319: W/System.err(32455): 499 [main] ERROR nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.PackageDocumentReader - Could not find table of contents resource. Tried resource with id '', toc, TOC and any NCX resource.
 02-04 16:33:54.319: W/System.err(32455): 500 [main] ERROR nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.NCXDocument - Book does not contain a table of contents file
 02-04 16:33:54.319: I/author(32455):  : [Dylan, Jesse]
 02-04 16:33:54.319: I/title(32455):  : Thomas Cole - The Voyage of Life
 02-04 16:33:54.329: D/dalvikvm(32455): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1038K, 19% free 7619K/9352K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
 02-04 16:33:54.329: I/dalvikvm-heap(32455): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.541MB for 970907-byte allocation
 02-04 16:33:54.349: D/dalvikvm(32455): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 17% free 8567K/10304K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 16ms
 02-04 16:33:54.349: D/dalvikvm(32455): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
 02-04 16:33:54.349: D/dalvikvm(32455): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
 02-04 16:33:54.369: D/dalvikvm(32455): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 17% free 8567K/10304K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
 02-04 16:33:54.369: I/dalvikvm-heap(32455): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.392MB for 1941798-byte allocation
 02-04 16:33:54.369: D/dalvikvm(32455): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
 02-04 16:33:54.369: I/dalvikvm-heap(32455): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.392MB for 24-byte allocation
 02-04 16:33:54.389: D/dalvikvm(32455): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 15% free 10463K/12204K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
 02-04 16:33:54.409: D/dalvikvm(32455): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 15% free 10464K/12204K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 21ms
 02-04 16:33:54.809: D/dalvikvm(32455): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 15% free 10464K/12204K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
 02-04 16:33:54.819: I/dalvikvm-heap(32455): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.118MB for 1807698-byte allocation
 02-04 16:33:54.839: D/dalvikvm(32455): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1896K, 27% free 10333K/13972K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
 02-04 16:33:54.869: D/dalvikvm(32455): GC_CONCURRENT freed 951K, 33% free 9395K/13972K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 22ms
 02-04 16:33:54.889: D/libEGL(32455): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
 02-04 16:33:54.909: D/libEGL(32455): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
 02-04 16:33:54.919: D/libEGL(32455): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
 02-04 16:33:54.939: D/OpenGLRenderer(32455): Enabling debug mode 0
 02-04 16:33:55.009: D/TilesManager(32455): Starting TG #0, 0x651f1f78
 02-04 16:33:55.009: D/TilesManager(32455): new EGLContext from framework: 64df0f40 
 02-04 16:33:55.009: D/GLWebViewState(32455): Reinit shader
```

I am getting blank screen instead of content of epub !! How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  WebView webview;
String line, line1 = "", finalstr = "";
int i = 0;
Book book;
String linez;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
   try {
        // find InputStream for book
        InputStream epubInputStream = assetManager
                .open("widget.epub");

        // Load Book from inputStream
        book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);

        // Log the book's authors
        Log.i("author", " : " + book.getMetadata().getAuthors());

        // Log the book's title
        Log.i("title", " : " + book.getTitle());

        /* Log the book's coverimage property */
         Bitmap coverImage =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(book.getCoverImage().getInputStream());
        Log.i("epublib", "Coverimage is " + coverImage.getWidth() +  " by " + coverImage.getHeight() + " pixels");

        // Log the tale of contents

       logTableOfContents(book.getTableOfContents().getTocReferences(), 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("epublib exception", e.getMessage());
    }
    Spine spine = book.getSpine(); 
    List<SpineReference> spineList = spine.getSpineReferences() ;
    int count = spineList.size();
    TextView tv=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(count));
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; count > i; i++) {
        Resource res = spine.getResource(i);

        try {
            InputStream is = res.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    linez =   string.append(line + "\n").toString();


                }

            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            //do something with stream
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    webview.loadData(linez, "text/html", "utf-8");
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void logTableOfContents(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth) {
    if (tocReferences == null) {

        return;
    }

    for (TOCReference tocReference : tocReferences) {
        StringBuilder tocString = new StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
         tocString.append("\t");
         }
         tocString.append(tocReference.getTitle());
         Log.i("TOC", tocString.toString());

        try {
            InputStream is = tocReference.getResource().getInputStream();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                // line1 = Html.fromHtml(line).toString();
                Log.v("line" + i, Html.fromHtml(line).toString());
                // line1 = (tocString.append(Html.fromHtml(line).toString()+
                // "\n")).toString();
                line1 = line1.concat(Html.fromHtml(line).toString());
            }
            finalstr = finalstr.concat("\n").concat(line1);
            // Log.v("Content " + i, finalstr);
            i++;
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        logTableOfContents(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1);
    }

    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", finalstr, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
}
}
```